# Microsoft Edge PDF scrolling and highlight issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, pdf, microsoft-edge

The Issue is, that in **Microsoft Edge** the PDF-View **doens't** let me **scroll** the **PDF File** with the mouse wheel. Neither it lets me click on links nor highlight some text. All these functions work properly with Internet Explorer. Buttons like Zoom in/out work fine and I can scroll the pdf with page up/down.

I've tried something with jquery, whereas I would ask for mouseover/mouseout of the #elementobject. The weird thing is, that both Events get fired simultaneously, when I mouseover the element. Could there be a focus issue?

What could be the solotion to this?

HTML Code:

```
<!--Container for PDF View-->
<div class="elementview">
  <iframe id="elementobject" src="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <p><b>Die Datei konnte nicht geöffnet werden!</b> <br/> Bitte Zugriff auf die Datei überprüfen.</p>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

jquery-Code:

```
//Open PDF-View
$(".elementcontent1").on("click", function () {
  var curlink = $(this).attr("id");
  $("#elementobject").attr('src', curlink); //Attach link for desired PDF-File
  $(".elementview").css({ 'height': $(window).height() }); //Adjust Hight of PDF Viewer

  if (elementstate == false) {  
    $(".elementview").toggle();  //Show PDF Viewer
    elementstate = true;
  }

  //Scroll to PDF
  $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({ 
    scrollTop: $("#elementobject").offset().top
  }, 200);

});//end onclick
```

CSS-Code:

```
.elementview{
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: none;
}
.elementview p{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To have clarity on this issue and guide you accordingly, kindly help us with the following information.

- Which build of Windows 10 is installed on the machine?(Search winver from the Start menu to know the same)
- What version of Edge are you using?

Please try the methods listed below.

**Method 1**

Clear Edge browsing history and cached data to see if it helps.

Your browser automatically saves temporary Internet files to help pages load faster. Clearing this cache will sometimes fix page display problems.

Open Microsoft **Edge**, select **History**> **Clear history**. Select **Browsing historyand Cached data and files,** and then select **Clear** to clear the same.

**Method 2**

If clearing Edge browsing history and cached data doesn’t fix the issue, reset Edge.

Open **Settings** and navigate to **Apps** > **Apps & features** > **Microsoft Edge**.

Click on **Advanced Options** and choose **Repair** or **Reset**.

Note:

**Resetting Edge** will remove your history, cookies, and many settings that were changed.

Besides， some of the common problems on Microsoft Edge are solved by updating Windows 10. Run Windows Update to help correct problems by replacing outdated files, updating drivers, and fixing vulnerabilities.

To check for updates, select the **Start** button, then select **Settings** > **Update & Security** > **Windows Update**, and then select Check for updates. If Windows Update says your PC is current, you have all the current updates.

**Edit:**

You could try to create an Object element and use it to display the PDF file. Code as below:

```
<input type="button" class="elementcontent1" value="click me" id="44678.pdf" />
<!--Container for PDF View-->
<div class="elementview" id="divcontent" style="width:900px; height:1000px"> 
</div> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".elementcontent1").on("click", function () { 
            var object = document.createElement('object');
            object.setAttribute('id', 'elementobject');
            object.setAttribute('data', $(this).attr("id"));
            object.setAttribute('type', 'application/pdf');
            object.setAttribute('width', '100%');
            object.setAttribute('height', '100%');  
            $("#divcontent").append(object);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: My **main computer** is running on Windows 10 Build **18362.476** and Microsoft Edge **44.18362.449.0**. But I'd rather think its a code problem. Since I've the same issue on multiple computers including my corporate notebook (Windows 10 Build **17134.1130 / Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1098.0**). 

I've tried Method 1 and Method 2. Both did not solve the issue.

Comment: Please refer to the above code and use the Object tag to display the PDF file.